# Cannot Launch Interactive Program While Piping to Script in Python

Tags: python, subprocess, interactive, nano

I have a python script that needs to call the defined `$EDITOR` or `$VISUAL`. When the Python script is called alone, I am able to launch the `$EDITOR` without a hitch, but the moment I pipe something to the Python script, the `$EDITOR` is unable to launch. Right now, I am using nano which shows

> Received SIGHUP or SIGTERM

every time. It appears to be the same issue [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249917/python-subprocess-sends-sigterm-to-other-processes).

```
sinister:Programming [1313]$ echo "import os;os.system('nano')" > "sample.py" 
sinister:Programming [1314]$ python sample.py
# nano is successfully launched here.
sinister:Programming [1315]$ echo "It dies here." | python sample.py 
Received SIGHUP or SIGTERM

Buffer written to nano.save.1
```

EDIT: Clarification; inside the program, I am not piping to the editor. The code is as follows:

```
editorprocess = subprocess.Popen([editor or "vi", temppath])
editorreturncode = os.waitpid(editorprocess.pid, 0)[1]
```

Comment: Can you paste some easy reproducer code? :)

Comment: Cannot catch you, do you want to start an editor from running a python script and keep the terminal input as standard input?

Comment: @xiao Yes, that is what I wanted to do. Nicholas's solution does just that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you pipe something to a process, the pipe is connected to that process's standard input.  This means your terminal input won't be connected to the editor.  Most editors also check whether their standard input is a terminal ([isatty](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/isatty.html)), which a pipe isn't; and if it isn't a terminal, they'll refuse to start.  In the case of `nano`, this appears to cause it to exit with the message you included:

```
% echo | nano
Received SIGHUP or SIGTERM
```

You'll need to provide the input to your Python script in another way, such as via a file, if you want to be able to pass its standard input to a terminal-based editor.

Now you've clarified your question, that you don't want the Python process's `stdin` attached to the editor, you can modify your code as follows:

```
editorprocess = subprocess.Popen([editor or "vi", temppath],
                                 stdin=open('/dev/tty', 'r'))
```

Comment: @eric, But `echo hi | vidir` still fails, same as your script. `echo hi | mutt` doesn't even try to start the editor, it tries to run in `mail(1)`-like fashion...

Comment: Well, you can feel free to rewrite your kernel, but seriously, that's how Unix-like OSes work. When `mutt` spawns an editor, it uses a temporary file for exactly this reason.

Comment: @sarnold try `vidir -` instead; `find -type f | vidir -`

Comment: `vidir` uses `/dev/tty`, which may not work everywhere, but if you don't mind that, close standard input and reopen it with that file.

Comment: @Nicholas I am using a temporary file; inside the program I call ["nano", tempfile] and that still doesn't fix the issue. I am not piping to the editor.

Comment: @Nicholas how do I go about replicating the `/dev/tty` usage in vidir? I looked at the source code, but I am unable to functionally replicate it in Python.

Comment: @Eric: See my edited answer. It's pretty simple to do it.  (When in doubt, more information and code is always better :-)

Comment: @Nicholas Thanks. I was doing it the os.open way as shown in sarnold's post, but I was trying `sys.std = os.open(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

The specific case of `find -type f | vidir -` is handled here:

```
foreach my $item (@ARGV) {
    if ($item eq "-") {
        push @dir, map { chomp; $_ } <STDIN>;
        close STDIN;
        open(STDIN, "/dev/tty") || die "reopen: $!\n";
    }
```

You can re-create this behavior in Python, as well:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import sys

sys.stdin.close()
o = os.open("/dev/tty", os.O_RDONLY)
os.dup2(o, 0)
os.system('vim')
```

Of course, it *closes* the standard input file descriptor, so if you intend on reading from it again after starting the editor, you should probably duplicate its file descriptor before closing it.

Comment: This works as well, but I am marking Nicholas' reply as the preferred solution since it does not require stdin to be closed. Thank you.

Comment: @Eric, yeah, his answer struck me as quite elegant when I saw it :) more useful for library routines.