# system() fails when piping stuff in

Tags: c, piping

Here's an example code to reproduce my problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char *f = "toto.txt";
    char cmd[64];

    sprintf(cmd, "nano %s", f);
    system(cmd);
    return 0;
}
```

If I do:

```
./test
```

Everything is fine, but if I do:

```
echo "blah"|./test
```

Nano fails:

```
received SIGHUP or SIGTERM
```

Is there a safer way to execute system commands ? 
I've already tried redirecting stdin.

Comment: AFAIK, piping is implemented by the shell (e.g., Bash), so it is not available through `system()`.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5986544/cannot-launch-interactive-program-while-piping-to-script-in-python

Comment: @Claudio But he is not trying to do that... it's the program's behavior that changes depending on how OP invokes it *from the shell.*

Comment: The error message about SIGHUP comes from nano. You can try running nano from the shell (echo "blah" | nano somefile") and it'll still show the same message.

Comment: @DanFego indeed it does. I guess I won't be using stdin, then. No big deal :)

Comment: I just didn't expect the piped message to go trought system(). But as system() uses the shell, I guess it makes sense ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `system`'ed program inherits its stdin from the process that called `system`. In the case of `nano` (and most other text editors, I'd imagine) this is a bad thing when stdin is not the terminal.

You should be able to fix it by adding `< /dev/tty` to the command string.

```
sprintf(cmd, "nano %s < /dev/tty", f);
```

You could check whether stdin is a tty first, and only apply the redirection when it's needed, like this:

```
if(isatty(0))
    sprintf(cmd, "nano %s", f);
else
    sprintf(cmd, "nano %s < /dev/tty", f);
```

(You're going to get bit when your `f` has any shell metacharacters in it, but that's an unrelated issue...)